# If a homogeneous polynomial on $S^2$ is zero then it is also zero on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

In Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians* he states:

> Note that if $p$ is a homogeneous polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^3$ of some degree $\ell$, then the restriction of $p$ to $S^2$ is identically zero only if $p$ itself is identically zero. After all, if $p$ is homogeneous of degree $\ell$ and zero on $S^2$, then $$p(x) = |x|^\ell p\Big(\frac{x}{|x|}\Big) = 0$$ for all $x \neq 0$, and hence, by continuity for all of $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

I am trying to understand the last part of the above: how does continuity extend $p$ being zero to all of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Note that he is stating that the equation holds for all $x\not=0$. Continuity is used to show that $p(0)=0$.

Comment: @morrowmh Thank you, as a follow up how does continuity show that $p(0) = 0$? I intuitively see why this is true, but how would one show it rigorously?

Comment: Hint: continuity implies $p(0)=\lim_{x\to0}p(x)$. Since $p(x)=0$ for all $x\not=0$, what is this limit?

Comment: @morrowmh Oh that was a lot simpler than I thought, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would show it like this.

Any $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^3$ outside of $S^2$ is the scalar multiple of some $x$ on the boundary of $S^2$. Say $x^* = rx$, $0 < r\in\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore
$$ p(x^*) = |rx|p\left(\frac{rx}{|rx|}\right) = r|x|p\left(\frac{rx}{r|x|}\right)=r|x|p\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)=rp(x)=0 $$
where the last equality holds since $p$ is zero on $S^2$.

Comment: Why does continuity imply $p(xr)=rp(x)$? This is false for, say, $p(x)=x^2$.

Comment: I was hasty and mixed it up with another result.. It's obviously not true. Removed that from my answer